# Finding duplicates out of the results which is grouped by two columns in SQL

Tags: sql

Please let me know whats wrong with the below query, saying cnt is unknown column.

```
SELECT SerialNumber, StoreCode, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM serialnumberheader
GROUP BY serialnumber, StoreCode
having cnt > 1
```

Comment: Scope issue. Do `having COUNT(*)  > 1` instead.

Comment: you can't use alias cnt in your having clause

Answer (score 1):

The `HAVING` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` list, so it cannot refer to that column alias.

```
SELECT SerialNumber, StoreCode, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM serialnumberheader
GROUP BY serialnumber, StoreCode
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Alternatively, wrap your query up in a derived table:

```
select SerialNumber, StoreCode, cnt
from
(
    SELECT SerialNumber, StoreCode, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM serialnumberheader
    GROUP BY serialnumber, StoreCode
) dt
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , given query is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some (all?) [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms)s don't let you use column aliases in the `where` and `having` clauses. You can just use the expression that you aliased directly:

```
SELECT   SerialNumber, StoreCode, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM     serialnumberheader
GROUP BY SerialNumber, StoreCode
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: ANSI SQL say it's not possible, but some (at least one) dbms allow it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT   SerialNumber, StoreCode, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM     serialnumberheader
GROUP BY SerialNumber, StoreCode
HAVING   COUNT(1) > 1
```